# Why would my dynamo queries occasionally not return a message

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

Every so often my queries to dynamo are never returned. My node code will make the request but the data is never returned. This what my query looks, surrounded with log statements. The dynamo table does have auto-scaling enabled. It has not logs of throttling or latency corresponding with these messages.

```
console.log(params);
results = await docClient.query(params).promise();
console.log(params, results);
```

This is the metrics over 12 hours, so it isn't happening much.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is very unlikely. Are you sure it's this http request that causes the lambda to timeout?

Comment: That looks like a lambda task which has hit a 30s maximum execution time, and therefore shutdown before your results arrive. You could increase your maximum execution time. Are you using provisioned or on-demand throughput on your dynamo table?